# Natural/Artificial distinction

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Is there in reality a distinction between natural and man-made products?

Can airplane be considered natural as much as a squirel or a mountain?

Comment: See [Natural Kinds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/natural-kinds/).

Comment: Hard core realists believe there is, "natural" notions "*carve nature at the joints*", as Plato put it, exist as real universals, artificial ones do not. Of course, this is controversial, and nominalists deny such things.